# Time required for balls to cool down

Tags: mechanical-engineering, heat-transfer, thermal-conduction

Two balls A and B, made of different materials, having the same radius, are initially heated to the same temperature $T_i$ and then are kept in the same environment which is at a temperature $T_\infty$. The heat transfer happens via convection to the environment with the same heat transfer coefficient in both the cases. Both the balls at some point of time reach to equilibrium with the environment.

Say that the thermal diffusivity of the material of ball A > thermal diffusivity of material of B

An educator of mine, mentioned that since A has a higher thermal diffusivity than B, A cools faster, i.e. $t_{a}$ < $t_{b}$, where $t$ is the time required for cooling.

However I feel, $\alpha$ is not the only one which will decide the cooling time.
I will use Heisler's Chart to explain why. (please check the edit also)

[image]
The non dimensional temperature difference will be same at the equilibrium i.e. 0. However for both the materials the Biot number will be different since they will have different thermal conductivities. Consequently, for both the balls Fourier number will be different when they reach to $T_\infty$. (as shown by the blue and green lines in the graph, I have taken any value of Fo at the end of cooling, I just want to convey the idea that Fo will be different for both the balls at equilibrium).

time required for cooling will then be,

$$t_{a}= \frac{r_o ^2}{\alpha_a}Fo_a$$

$$t_{b}= \frac{r_o ^2}{\alpha_b}Fo_b$$

As we can see time required to reach T$_\infty$ not only depends on $\alpha$ but on the Fourier number.

Even though the thermal diffusivity of A is greater than that of B which is trying to reduce the time required to cool for A, it may be the case that Fo for A is much more greater than that for B which increases the time required for cooling in case of A.

> So, I argue that just by a knowledge of thermal diffusivity you can't tell which one would cool faster. It also depends on the Fourier Number, for same dimensions. Am I right here?

Even simply by looking at the conduction equation one can conclude that temperature variation with time of a layer of thickness dr taken at a particular r, will depend on both thermal diffusivity and temperature gradient.

$\alpha$ surely is a measure of how quick the temperature changes with time, but not the only measure.

[image]

Comment: Given the complexity of the world, if two concepts are not the same, then one can usually be made to do something independent of the other (but dependent on a multitude of other things that make it only so in a limited region).  Some people may consider pointing out these differences nitpicking on less typical cases.  I just consider their statements on the typical case to carry implicit constraints.

Comment: Now that you have used general arguments, do a specific case. Choose two materials with $k$ differing by a factor, for example 2. Start by setting the same heat capacity $\rho\tilde{C}_p$ values for the materials. What happens? Now increase or decrease the heat capacity values by a factor of 2 or 1/2. What happens?

Comment: The Fourier number is $\alpha$*$t$/$L$, so knowing $\alpha$ also tells you how the Fourier number will contribute to scenario.

Comment: @Abel So, maybe the educator just vaguely resorted to saying that one with a higher alpha will cool faster, what he meant was for a constant Fo. In any case, is this method for determining the time required for cooling correct? (I mean, the equations that I have shared in the ques)

Comment: In the real world it is done with thermocouples. Thermocouples are put into the ball to measure the cooling rates in various quench media for metal heat-treatment.

Comment: In the situation you state, everything but $\alpha$ is fixed at the same value for both balls so $\alpha$ is the remaining variable to base any conclusion of how the balls will differ. A temperature gradient must exist to enable heat transfer, but if both balls are equilibrated to the same surroundings and the same temperature, then the gradients will also be the same.

Comment: @J.Ari Thanks for the response. I don't get how the temperature gradients will be the same for both the balls? I think that because both the materials are different they will have different temperature profiles at any time.

Comment: @HarshitRajput Are you asking about the gradient between the surface and the surroundings or within each ball, which is what posting the conduction heat equation implies to me. It looks like this is becoming 2 questions.

Comment: No, I'm sticking by the question. As you said " if both balls are equilibrated to the same surroundings and the same temperature (which is the case in my ques), then the gradients will also be the same". How the gradients will be the same? I interpret from your quoted statement that, at any time t and r in both the balls, the left hand side term will be the same in last equation (in the ques).

Comment: @HarshitRajput The second sentence in the post mentions convection and later the conduction heat transfer equation is added. So are we talking about conduction of heat through the ball to the surface or convective heat transfer away from the surface to the surroundings. I want to make sure I am trying to answer your actual question, which isn't clear to me.

Comment: Oh, yes we're just interested in the conduction within the ball.